# Boolean expression optimization in compiler and high end processor pipeline

Tags: gcc, optimization, compilation, mathematical-optimization, pipeline

I want to calculate a boolean expression. For ease of understanding let's assume the expression is,

O=( A & B & C) | ( D & E & F)---(eqn. 1),

Here A, B, C, D, E and F are random bits. Now, as my target platform is high-end intel i7-Haswell processor that supports 64 bit data type, I can make this much more efficient using bit-slicing.
So now, O, A, B, C, D, E and f are 64 bits data type,

O_64=( A_64 & B_64 & C_64) | ( D_64 & E_64 & F_64)---(eqn. 2), the & and | are bitwise operators similar to C language.

Now, I need the expression to take constant time to execute. That means, the calculation of Eqn. 2 should take the exact number of steps in the processor irrespective of the values in A_64, B_64, C_64, D_64, E_64, and F_64. The values are filled up using a random generator in the runtime.

Now my question is,

1. Considering I am using GCC or GCC-7 with -O3, How far can the compiler optimize the expression? for example, if A_64 becomes all zeroes (can happen with probability 2^{-64} ) Then we don't need to calculate the first part of eqn.2 then O_64 becomes equal to D_64 & E_64 & F_64. Is it possible for a c compiler to optimize such a way? We have to remember that the values are filled up at runtime and the boolean expressions have around 120 variables.
2. Is it possible for a for a processor to do such an optimization (List 1) during runtime? As my boolean expression is very long, the execution will be heavily pipelined, now is it possible for a processor to pull out an operation out of the pipeline in if such a situation arises?

Please, let me know if any part of the question is not understandable.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for a c compiler to optimize such a way?

It's allowed to do it, but it probably won't. There is nothing to gain in general. If part of the expression was statically known to be zero, that would be used. But inserting branches inside bitwise calculations is almost always counterproductive, and I've never seen a compiler judge a sequence of ANDs to be "long enough to be worth inserting an early-out" (you can certainly do so manually, of course). If you need a hard guarantee of course I can't give you that, if you want to be *sure* you should always check the assembly.

What it probably will do (for longer expressions at least) is reassociate the expression for more instruction-level parallelism. So code like that probably won't be just two long (but parallel with each other) chains of dependent ANDs, but be split up into more chains. That still wouldn't make the time depend on the values.

> Is it possible for a for a processor to do such an optimization during runtime?

Extremely hypothetically yes. No processor architecture that I am aware of does that. It would be a slightly tricky mechanism, and as a general rule it would almost never help.

Hypothetically it could work like this: when the operands for an AND instruction are looked up and one (or both) of them is found to be renamed to the hard-wired zero-register, the renamer can immediately rename the destination to zero as well (rather than allocating a new register for the result), effectively giving that AND instruction 0-latency. The flags output would also be known so the µop would not even have to be executed. It would roughly be a cross between copy-elimination and a zeroing idiom.

That mechanism wouldn't even trigger unless one of the inputs is set to zero with a zeroing idiom, if an input is *accidentally* zero that wouldn't be detected. It would also not completely remove the influence of the redundant AND instructions, they still have to go through (most of) the front-end of the processor even if it is just to find out that they didn't need to be executed after all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As far as I got, the bottom line is neither the compiler or the microprocessor (of course the one we know) optimization can make the code non-constant time, right?

Comment: @Rick - well read what _harold_ actually said, which can be summarized as "Both cases are possible but unlikely". Personally I haven't seen or heard of any compiler or CPU implementing such optimizations. If it is very important to you, you could implement the critical part of the code in assembly, to at least remove the compiler from the equation.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Actually that is the problem, I can't. The code needs to be portable, and so the assembly is out of picture.